# Yeoman: can you call a method from within a template?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

Can you call a method from within a Yeoman template, in place of where a templateData property is normally injected?

I'm looking to generate a random guid multiple times within a template. In my _Product.xml template file I have:-

```
<someNode value="<%= randomGuid %>">
<someNode value="<%= randomGuid %>">
<someNode value="<%= randomGuid %>">
<someNode value="<%= randomGuid %>">
<someNode value="<%= randomGuid %>">
```

Then in my yeoman generator I have:-

```
_buildTemplateData() {
  this.templatedata.randomGuid = uuid.v4();
}

writeToDisk() {
  this.fs.copyTpl(this.templatePath('_Product.xml'), this.destinationPath('Product.xml'), this.templatedata);
}
```

And I was hoping to get:-

```
<someNode value="43EE86E4-AC19-4A82-A053-7FE0857AB1F5"/>
<someNode value="7F7184CF-23A7-4383-B5BB-E3A383BC6A0A"/>
<someNode value="5B7A26C1-A449-4B35-94E3-D214C62CEAD7"/>
<someNode value="641D7EC0-AFB1-4646-8B52-5DC71B8FFC50"/>
<someNode value="CEB94BA1-D487-4838-A354-FAFB4D8B188A"/>
```

but instead I get:-

```
<someNode value="43EE86E4-AC19-4A82-A053-7FE0857AB1F5"/>
<someNode value="43EE86E4-AC19-4A82-A053-7FE0857AB1F5"/>
<someNode value="43EE86E4-AC19-4A82-A053-7FE0857AB1F5"/>
<someNode value="43EE86E4-AC19-4A82-A053-7FE0857AB1F5"/>
<someNode value="43EE86E4-AC19-4A82-A053-7FE0857AB1F5"/>
```

I know I could create a bunch of Guids as properties of templateData, and pass them all in, referencing each one individually, but I'd like to avoid that as I have no need to reuse the guid outside of the Product.xml file, and I'd like to trim down the code as much as possible.
I'm also looking to do something similar with a function call....but this is the more basic example to post here.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. Pass a function as template context:

```
this.fs.copyTpl(a, b, {
  getUuid: () => uuid.v4()
});
```

Then call it in your template:

```
<someNode value="<%= getUuid() %>">
```